# Спарсить строку, разделив ее пробелами, Java

Tags: java, алгоритм

Здравствуйте.

Допустим, имеется строка такого вида : 
**Youremail@gmail.comAnotheremail@gmail.com**
Как спарсить эту строку так, чтобы в результате получить лист, в котором каждый элемент -- отдельная почта, т.е. 
**youremail@gmail.com** **anotheremail@gmail.com**

И да, таких элементов очень много, т.е. решение должно быть не слишком медленным

UPD всем большое спасибо

Comment: Гарантируется ли, что адреса почты корректны и расположены в существующих доменных зонах 1 уровня?

Comment: да, гарантируется.

Comment: могу написать код некоторого "костыля" на C# или C++, сумеете "перевести"?

Comment: да, конечно. Но костыль и я сейчас пишу, используя StringBuffer, находя в строке ".com", и после этого добавляя " " к строке, а после этого через split разделяю строку на отдельные элементы, добавляя их в лист

Comment: а потом костыль напорется на пользователя с почтой mail.ru - и всё будет плохо :D

Comment: а вот и нет, программа работает онли с gmail

Comment: @Schepalin попробуйте такой вариант https://ideone.com/5E78VO   ...... сколько по времени будет делать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а вот и баг в вашем решении: https://ideone.com/9RREEh :) (там я тестовые данные изменил немножко)

Comment: @Schullz да это понятно. я же не знаю какие валидные емейлы.. Если в них допускаются точки, тогда просто вместо `.com` сделать `@gmail.com` и предварительно вычислить `length` от этой строки и подставлять....... проблем-то)

Comment: @Schullz вот форк на такой случай))) https://ideone.com/OkRYll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку автор уточнил в комментариях, что код на C++ его тоже устроит, и уточнил "ТЗ", привожу код, который разделяет строку, содержащую несколько корректных gmail.com адресов на список адресов

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string> getAddrs(string s)
{
    const string tail = "@gmail.com";
    string lst;
    string cur;
    vector<string> res;

    for (int i = 0; i < (int) s.size(); i++)
    {
        if (lst.size() >= tail.size())
            lst = lst.substr(1);
        lst += s[i];
        cur += s[i];
        if (lst == tail)
        {
            res.push_back(cur);
            cur = "";
        }           
    }
    return res;
}

int main() 
{
    string str = "Youremail@gmail.comAnotheremail@gmail.com";
    vector<string> res = getAddrs(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) res.size(); i++)
        cout << res[i] << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: то же самое решение)) спасибо) щас буду замерять, с какой скоростью он обработает 5кк элементов и запишет их в другой txt

Comment: Есть риск нарваться при адресе типа `my.cm@gmail.com`. Жаль, автор сразу в вопросе не указал, что там только gmail - тогда делать нефиг. Я бы для пущей простоты пробежался по строке, заменяя все `@gmail.com` (именно начиная с `@`, чтоб гарантированно не нарваться на странный адрес) на пробелы, и получил бы строку имен. После чего добавить к каждому `@gmail.com` - уже вообще неффиг делать.

Comment: @Harry были опасения, что в gmail тоже можно точки добавлять - и получить какой-нибудь g.ma.il. Уточнил - нельзя. Но я подправил решение.

А вообще да, с заменой "@gmail.com" на пробелы с последующим разделением строки - гораздо более красивое решение, почти совсем без костылей

Answer (score 2):

Я бы вам порекомендовал сделать так, чтоб эти емейлы были разделены чем-то существенным, что не может входить в имя почты, например две звездочки `**` или два доллара `$$`, а потом банально разбить строки по этому разделителю через  `.split("\\*\\*")` и сложить это в лист. Меньше геморроя на свою голову и не придется мозг выворачивать регулярками и прочей ерундой.

Метод `split` возвращает новый массив. Строка бьется по разделителю, указанным первым аргументом.

Пример

```
String Str = new String("Youremail@gmail.com$$Anotheremail@gmail.com");

List<String> emailList =  new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(Str.split("\\$\\$")));

System.out.println("Emails:" );
for (String email: emailList){
    System.out.println(email);
}
```

выведет:

```
Emails:
Youremail@gmail.com
Anotheremail@gmail.com
```

---

Вот вариант на случай, когда известно, что все почтовые ящики будет на конкретном домене.
Значит мы будем знать, что оканчиваться они будут все на `@somedomain2level.domain1level`

Соответственно, можно задать этот параметр для поиска в строке, и в цикле по этому параметру найти каждую почту, перемещая курсор на следующую позицию для поиска

```
String string = "Youremail@gmail.comAnotheremail@gmail.comSomeemail@gmail.com";

int prevPos = 0, nextPos;
List<String> emailList = new ArrayList<>();
final String SEARCH_STR = "@gmail.com";
final int SEARCH_STR_LENGTH = SEARCH_STR.length();

/**** start code *****/
while (true) {
    nextPos = string.indexOf(SEARCH_STR, prevPos);
    if (nextPos == -1)
        break;

    emailList.add(string.substring(prevPos, nextPos + SEARCH_STR_LENGTH));
    prevPos = nextPos + SEARCH_STR_LENGTH;
}
/**** end code *****/

for (String test : emailList) {
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

https://ideone.com/OkRYll

Comment: Спасибо, но дело в том, что строка, которую парсер получает на вход уже заготовлена (т.е. разделители мы можем вставить только вручную, изменяя текстовый файл, который парсим), т.е. этот вариант отпадает

Comment: @Schepalin у вас в этом текстовом файле все емейлы расположены в одну строку? Или все же каждый на новой строке? Если в одну, то откуда они берутся чтоб складироваться в одну строку?

Comment: Почтовых адресов около 5млн, расположены они слитно, где-то 7-10 почт на одну строку

Comment: в любом случае, спасибо за ответ

Comment: @Schepalin дополнил тем, что описал в комментарии. Можете попробовать. А вдруг...

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<String> parseEmails(String emails, String domain) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(emails.split(domain));
    String temp;
    for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        temp = list.get(i);
        list.set(i, temp + domain);
    }
    return list;
}

public static void main(String []args){
    List<String> mailList = parseEmails("Youremail@gmail.comAnotheremail@gmail.com", "@gmail.com");
    for(String mail : mailList) {
        System.out.println(mail);
    }
}
```

Comment: Здесь принято давать пояснения к ответам, а не только код.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий по теме вопроса.